# How to determine image colorspace using WIC?

Tags: image, colors, wic

How can I determine the colorspace of an image using WIC? I want to know if an image is RGB, CMYK or mono(B/W). I would prefer not looking at every color format available.

Why I want to know is I want to use IWICColorContext::InitializeFromFilename method but to give it a proper profile I need to know if the image is RGB, CMYK or mono.

Comment: You can get the IWICColorContext from a wic frame directly. Is it what you want?

Comment: What I want to know is there an API that will tell me if a image file is RGB, CMYK, etc or do I have to determine this by looking at all the possible pixel format GUIDs? I want to know this so that if I display a number of ICC profiles to the user the only ones I want to show are the ones that would apply to the image's high level pixel format (RGB, CMYK, etc) So in order to do so I need the image colorspace.

Comment: The "is CMYK" notion is not available as such from any WIC interface or property. However pixel format names are normalized with a naming convention, so if it contains "CMYK", it's a CMYK format: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797.aspx#cmyk_pixel_formats do you want sample code that demonstrate how to get the format name from an image?

Comment: Simon, thanks - that is what I ending up doing, interrogating the pixel formats. Again thanks